# Sections with optional counting arguments

Tags: macros, sectioning, numbering, optional-arguments

I am back for more... =) I am actually trying to fix my own problems, and i feel i learn so much here. Thank you so much for helpin someone as clueless as me ^^

I am attempting to make a text, with a list of tasks. Oppgave in norwegian is the same as task. Each task should have a mandatory argument saying how much points the task is worth. The task, should also have an optional argument `alt` which will input the task as Alternative 1. Below is a minimal example of what I am looking for

```
\Oppgave{5}
\Oppgave{3}
\Oppgave{2}
\Oppgave{4}{Alt}
\Oppgave{4}{Alt}
\Oppgave{3}
\Oppgave{7}{Alt}
\Oppgave{7}{Alt}
\Oppgave{7}{Alt}
\Oppgave{9}
```

The output should look like this

> Oppgave 1 (5 poeng)
>
> Oppgave 2 (3 poeng)
>
> Oppgave 3 (2 poeng)
>
> Oppgave 4 Alternative I  (4 poeng)
>
> Oppgave 4 Alternative II (4 poeng)
>
> Oppgave 5 (3 poeng)
>
> Oppgave 6 Alternative I   (7 poeng)
>
> Oppgave 6 Alternative II  (7 poeng)
>
> Oppgave 6 Alternative III (7 poeng)
>
> Oppgave 7 (9 poeng)

Here is a minimal example of my work so far.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=3cm,vmargin=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcounter{problem}
\setcounter{problem}{1}

\newcommand{\oppgave}[1]{\section*{Oppgave \arabic{problem} {\normalfont    \normalsize (#1 poeng)}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Oppgave \arabic{problem} }} \stepcounter{problem} }

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\oppgave{3}

\oppgave{4}

\oppgave{2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's worth to take a look at the [exam](http://ctan.org/pkg/exam) class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the package [xparse](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) and to set the last argument as optional. Another method based on the clever idea of egreg (as usual). Instead of using an optional argument you can define a starred version which prints the alternative with a roman numeral instead. Both solution are implemented in the following example. (Thanks to egreg)

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\newcounter{problem}
\setcounter{problem}{0}
\newcounter{alternative}
\setcounter{alternative}{0}
\newif\iffirstalt
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\oppgave}{m o}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\setcounter{alternative}{0}\stepcounter{problem}\firstaltfalse}%
                  {\stepcounter{alternative}\iffirstalt\else\stepcounter{problem}\firstalttrue\fi}
  \section*{Oppgave \arabic{problem}%
             {\normalfont\IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{~Alternative \Roman{alternative}\ }
                \normalsize (#1 poeng)}%
   \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Oppgave \arabic{problem} }} 
}


\NewDocumentCommand{\oppgaveS}{s m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}%
     {\stepcounter{alternative}\iffirstalt\else\stepcounter{problem}\firstalttrue\fi}%
     {\setcounter{alternative}{0}\stepcounter{problem}\firstaltfalse}%
  \section*{Oppgave \arabic{problem}%
             {\normalfont\IfBooleanTF{#1}{~Alternative \Roman{alternative}\ }{}
                \normalsize (#2 poeng)}%
   \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Oppgave \arabic{problem} }} 
}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\oppgave{3}

\oppgave{4}

\oppgave{2}[a]

\oppgave{2}[a]


\oppgave{3}

\oppgave{2}[EVERY TEXT WILL BE IGNORED]


\oppgaveS{3}

\oppgaveS{4}

\oppgaveS*{2}

\oppgaveS*{2}

\oppgaveS{3}

\oppgaveS*{2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the OP wants `\oppgave` macros with optional arguments *not* to increase the `problem` counter (starting from the second macro).

Comment: Yes! that is correct lockstep. I attempted to fiddle around inside xparse, but it was quite hard =(

Comment: @lockstep: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I changed the code.

Comment: It's more complicated - the first `\oppgave` macro *with* optional argument following the macro without such argument *should* increase the counter. Only the follow-ups with optional argument shouldn't.

Comment: I would also preffer if the optional argument was a simple roman counter. I have no need for custom messages. Just a simple increasing roman counter. Etc I , II , III , VI , V and so on.
Great work so far ^^ hi seems complicated

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar: Please see my edit.

Comment: Really lovely solution!. Sorry for asking so much, I am really bad with latex... =( Is there any way so that i can also just write \Oppgave . And it will just return Oppgave 1 , and nothing else?

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar: It is also possible. I will edit my answer at the evening

Answer (score 2):

Since your alternative problems just need a "stepping" Roman numeral, just declare with `*` a problem that has alternatives:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\newcounter{problem}
\newcounter{alternative}[problem]
\renewcommand{\thealternative}{\Roman{alternative}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Oppgave}{s m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\ifnum\value{alternative}=0 \stepcounter{problem}\fi\stepcounter{alternative}}
    {\setcounter{alternative}{0}\stepcounter{problem}}
  \section*{Oppgave \arabic{problem}\space 
    \ifnum\value{alternative}>0 Alternative \thealternative\space\fi
   {\normalfont\normalsize (#2 poeng)}}
   \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Oppgave \arabic{problem}} 
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\Oppgave{5}
\Oppgave{3}
\Oppgave{2}
\Oppgave*{4}
\Oppgave*{4}
\Oppgave{3}
\Oppgave*{7}
\Oppgave*{7}
\Oppgave*{7}
\Oppgave{9}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can I adapt you solution ;-)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel You can do whatever you want; mine was inspired by yours, actually.